# Sequelize Many-to-Many add function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many

**package.json**

> "express": "^4.17.1",
>   "pg": "^7.17.1",
>   "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
>   "sequelize": "^5.21.3",

**There're two models:**

```
// User
const User = seq.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  login: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  age: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  isDeselected: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
  }
}, { timestamps: false });

export default User;

// Group
const Group = seq.define('group', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  permissions: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY
  }
}, { timestamps: false });

export default Group;
```

**There's group for association:**

```
import Group from './group';
import User from './user';

const UserGroup = seq.define('UserGroup');

Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserGroup });
User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: UserGroup });

seq.sync({ force:true }).then(() => { console.log("Tables have been created"); }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

**And method for adding user to group:**

```
UserModel.findOne({ where: { id: userIds } })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) { return; }
        GroupModel.findOne({ where: { id: groupId } })
          .then((group) => {
            if (!group) return;
            user.addGroup(group);
          });
```

**There's an error during executing:**

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: user.addGroup is not a function

Comment: make sure the User model has associations at the moment of executing user.addGroup(group); (look at associations in the user object).

Comment: I've run my project with existing code. Then, I've used postman and via route try to add group to existing user. And got this message in server console.

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the line user.addGroup(group) and look at the user object and its 'associations' prop.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is a working example:

```js
import { sequelize as seq } from '../../db';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const User = seq.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    login: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    isDeselected: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false },
);

const Group = seq.define(
  'group',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    permissions: {
      type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    },
  },
  { timestamps: false },
);

const UserGroup = seq.define('UserGroup', {});

Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserGroup });
User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: UserGroup });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await seq.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await User.bulkCreate(
      [
        { login: 'a', password: '123', groups: [{ name: 'group a' }, { name: 'group b' }] },
        { login: 'b', password: '321', groups: [{ name: 'group c' }, { name: 'group d' }] },
      ],
      { include: [Group] },
    );

    // test
    const userIds = [1, 2];
    const groupId = 3;
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: userIds } });
    const group = await Group.findOne({ where: { id: groupId } });
    const result = await user.addGroup(group);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await seq.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result and generated SQL:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "UserGroup" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "group" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" ("id"   SERIAL , "login" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "password" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "age" INTEGER, "isDeselected" BOOLEAN, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'user' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "group" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "group" ("id"  SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "permissions" VARCHAR(255)[], PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'group' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "UserGroup" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "UserGroup" ("groupId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "group" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "userId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "user" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("groupId","userId"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'UserGroup' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "user" ("id","login","password") VALUES (DEFAULT,'a','123'),(DEFAULT,'b','321') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "group" ("id","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,'group a'),(DEFAULT,'group b'),(DEFAULT,'group c'),(DEFAULT,'group d') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "UserGroup" ("groupId","userId") VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "login", "password", "age", "isDeselected" FROM "user" AS "user" WHERE "user"."id" IN (1, 2) LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "permissions" FROM "group" AS "group" WHERE "group"."id" = 3;
Executing (default): SELECT "groupId", "userId" FROM "UserGroup" AS "UserGroup" WHERE "UserGroup"."userId" = 1 AND "UserGroup"."groupId" IN (3);
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "UserGroup" ("groupId","userId") VALUES (3,1) RETURNING *;
[ UserGroup {
    dataValues: { userId: 1, groupId: 3 },
    _previousDataValues: { userId: 1, groupId: 3 },
    _changed: { userId: false, groupId: false },
    _modelOptions:
     { timestamps: false,
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: true,
       underscored: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: [Object],
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNull: false,
       sequelize: [Sequelize],
       hooks: {} },
    _options:
     { isNewRecord: true,
       _schema: null,
       _schemaDelimiter: '',
       include: undefined },
    isNewRecord: false } ]
```

data rows in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "user";
 id | login | password | age | isDeselected
----+-------+----------+-----+--------------
  1 | a     | 123      |     |
  2 | b     | 321      |     |
(2 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "group";
 id |  name   | permissions
----+---------+-------------
  1 | group a |
  2 | group b |
  3 | group c |
  4 | group d |
(4 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "UserGroup";
 groupId | userId
---------+--------
       1 |      1
       2 |      1
       3 |      2
       4 |      2
       3 |      1
(5 rows)
```

Dependencies versions:

```
"pg": "^7.17.1",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
"sequelize": "^5.21.3",
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/60686872